# Flappy Bird: is there a way to find the spawn - rate of the poles?

Tags: javascript

I have made a working Flappy Bird game, but the green poles are spawning in a weird way. I have done it like this:

- frameCount is a p5.js variable counting the frames
- draw is a p5.js function that will be done every frame

```
    let game_speed = 1;
    let max_speed = 1000;
    let spawn_rate = Math.round(max_speed / game_speed);
    function draw(){
      if(frameCount % spawn_rate === 0)
        generateNewPole();
      game_speed += (game_speed < max_speed / 10)? 0.001 : 0;
      spawn_rate = Math.round(max_speed / game_speed);
    }
```

I have tried the following formulas for the spawn_rate :

- Math.round(max_speed - game_speed)

  - This didn't work even close to good
- Math.round(max_speed / game_speed)

  - This worked ok, but I have random big gaps everywhere
- Math.round((max_speed - game_speed) / game_speed)

  - This worked also quite well, except for random gaps here too
- Math.round((max_speed - game_speed) / (max.speed / game.speed))

  - The poles spawned at a god-speed rate
- Math.round(max_speed / Math.round(game_speed))

  - Also random gaps
- if(Math.round(frameCount * game.speed) % max_speed === 0)

  - Yeah... not a single pole spawned at all

For the second and third things I tried (see above), I expected them to work, but there are still spaces. This might be because of JavaScript's way of handling decimal numbers (It sucks at it) or I am just dumb and doing something completely wrong

edit: here is a link to [my code](https://editor.p5js.org/Roel_04/sketches/bMro323YN)

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.round(max_speed / game_speed)
```

I can hazard a guess that the big gaps you describe are caused by `Math.round` when it switches from rounding down to rounding up (and vice versa). I suspect you'd get more consistant behaviour if you switched to `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil`.